# Like Skype application, how to show top bar status bar at ongoing call in foreground state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Here is requirement to show green top bar to indicate audio/video call is on in app foreground state. On action of top bar tap action, should back to calling window. Is there any api available in iOS sdk to do same. Please suggest your response would be very helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Here adding reference image of skype app, that use red bar to return to calling window.

I searched in stackoverflow, but their solution didn't work for me.

[image: Here adding reference image of skype app, that use **red bar** to return to calling window.]

Comment: The red bar is just an indication that an app is using the microphone in the background, so you will not be able to make it green.

Comment: @rckoenes bar color is not our priority just bar itself.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio evangelist here. The "tap status bar to return to call" feature is built-in to any app that uses [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) which was released with iOS 10. If you implement CallKit for your application you should get the status bar tap to return to call feature. Watch [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/) for more details.

Our new [Programmable Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started) SDK is in beta for iOS and will have new features soon to make CallKit even easier to implement. This [quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice-sdk/ios/getting-started) will get you up and running with that SDK if you're interested.

Comment: As we are not targeting iOS 10, do you have any solution to achive like skype did.

Comment: With CallKit the "tap status bar to return to call" only appears when the app is in the background. It disappears once you open the app. Any idea how to show it there when not in the call-screen and then make it disappear once in the call-screen?

Comment: I am using 'TwilioVideo', '~> 3.2' for video calling, but when I put my app in background during video call it's not showing me any status bar about ongoing calls. so do I have to do something to do that or it depends on TwilioVideo SDK?